# Replacement String Conditional on Match

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I would like to know if it's possible in most regex search-and-replace mechanisms to conditionally replace with a literal string based on whether a certain match has occurred. My working example is this *pair* of regex replaces:

`^(\s*([\S]*):.*function.*\((.+)\).*\{.*)$` -> `\1 console.info('\2 ::: \3:', \3);`
`^(\s*([\S]*):.*function.*\(\).*\{.*)$` -> `\1 console.info('\2');`

The first replaces lines such as:

```
test: function (arg1, arg2) {
    //pass
}
```

with:

```
test: function (arg1, arg2) { console.info('test2 ::: arg1, arg2:', arg1, arg2);
    //pass
}
```

and the second one does the same for functions with no arguments like:

```
test2: function () {
    //pass
}
```

I'm looking for a way to apply only a single search-and-replace to perform *both* of these tasks. One way, if this is possible, would be to essentially say "if I have `\3`, replace `::: \3:', \3`, else don't. Is this possible? Is there another way?

Comment: I have not seen any regex engine that can use alternatives in the replacement string.

Comment: Already answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080102/javascript-regex-replace-to-conditionally-remove-part-of-a-string

Comment: Have you looked into conditionals in regex? http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html

Comment: @OlexandrPetrov I understand how that allows me to conditionally have `\3` empty, but I don't see how it would let me conditionally insert literals such as the `:::` into my output?

Comment: Although conditional replacement is available in Boost-Extended Format String Syntax, from my testing, SublimeText seems to use Perl Format String Syntax: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format.html , which doesn't require `()` to be escape to follow principle of least surprise. There doesn't seem to be any option to change this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
var code = document.getElementById("code");
code.value = code.value.replace(/\b(function\s*(?:[\w.]+)?)\s+\((.*?)\)\s*{/g,function(match,p1,p2) {
    if (p2.length) {
        return match + "console.info('test2 ::: arg1, arg2:', p1, p2);"
    } else {
        return match + "console.info('other contents');"
    }
})
```

If your arguments are simple values*, you can do something like this

```
var code = document.getElementById("code");
code.value = code.value.replace(/\b(function\s*(?:[\w.]+)?)\s+\((.*?)\)\s*{/g,function(match,p1,p2) {
    if (p2.length) {
        var ParamsCount = p2.split(",").length;
        var ParamString = []
        for (p=0;p<ParamsCount;p++) {
            ParamString[p] = "'Arg" + p + ": ' + " + "arguments[" + p +"]"
        }
        return match + "console.log(" + ParamString.join(", ") + ")"
    } else {
        return match + "console.info('other contents');"
    }
})
```

- Because it does a rudimentary split based on a comma, arguments with nested commas would cause problems.. like `function foo(bar(1,2),"sample") {` or `function foo("hey, that's cool")` would each screw up the arguments.

Regex Explanation

```
`\b`                    # Token: \b (word boundary)
`(`                     # Opens CG1
    `function`          # Literal function
    `\s*`               # Token: \s (white space)
                          # * repeats zero or more times
    `(?:`               # Opens NCG
        `[\w.]+`        # Character class (any of the characters within)
                          # Token: \w (any alpha or numeric character)
                          # Any of: .
                          # + repeats one or more times
    `)?`                # Closes NCG
                          # ? repeats zero or one times
`)`                     # Closes CG1
`\s+`                   # Token: \s (white space)
                          # + repeats one or more times
`\(`                    # Literal (
`(`                     # Opens CG2
    `.*?`               # . denotes any single character, except for newline
                          # * repeats zero or more times
                          # ? as few times as possible
`)`                     # Closes CG2
`\)`                    # Literal )
`\s*`                   # Token: \s (white space)
                          # * repeats zero or more times
`{`                     # Literal {
```

JSFiddle (demo of both, just uncomment the single commented return): http://jsfiddle.net/rg23LL0p/